# Idea - long/wide code on Stack Overflow page - expand or open in bigger window

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, code

My idea is only for wide and long code, not easy to read without scroll left, right, up and down. Possibility to expand (when clicking on it or hover over) or open this code in a bigger window (button) will enable for moderator while editing (moderator tools).

Both previous questions (linked above) wanted general changes.

I have two solutions:

- Expanded window with a code when click on it or hover over.
- Open code in a bigger window (it calls: „Open in new window).

The best solution in my opinion is:
http://www.thinkandbuild.it/custom-controls-3d-touch-confirm/
I saw the second solution on androidbegin.com

Comment: or... you could use the scrollbar,

Comment: It the code is longer than a screen I have to go up, down- right, left...   So It will be more comfortable. We can find it on the new websides.

Comment: that'd be a case where there's simply too much code.

Comment: I could agree with this. There are a few situations where as the amount of code is large. I sometimes find myself having to scroll down to the scroll bar, scroll the code block to the right, then scroll back up to where I was reading the code. This often results in me leaving the question as I forgot where I was at. A simple expand button would not be difficult to enact....

Comment: @Kevin B. Yes. It will be very helpful to navigate.

Comment: i mean, my point is those posts need to be fixed and/or closed. we don't need a feature to deal with a few exceptions

Comment: @S. Walker I have the same when a code is long and wide. You can see how it works e.g. here:  http://www.thinkandbuild.it/custom-controls-3d-touch-confirm/

Comment: I  don't think it's too much to ask for the OP to format code in an easily readable manner before posting.

Comment: @MartinJames according to OPs, it's too much to ask them a lot of stuff....

Comment: @Patrice well, sure, testing and debugging details are just a dream, in most cases, but the code source should be easily readable.  If it's not, I vtc as 'Unclear'.

Comment: @KevinB: "*my point is those posts need to be fixed and/or closed. we don't need a feature to deal with a few exceptions*" Not every problem can be demonstrated in a couple lines of code. I defy you to show me genuinely useful Vulkan code that's shorter than a page.

Comment: You are right. Not every programming language and frameworks looks the same. We can see very long commands which we can't see on the end. The same long code for more than a page. I have met it in c#, java, swift, but that's only programming languages I use. When I will put a question with so long code (which is needed to see everythning) I know there will be not enought replays. When I will cut it to make it more readable it is not possible to run it in e.g. Android Studio or Xcode.

Comment: C# supports simple line continuation, so the only reason why you are seeing a scrollbar with C# code is because the person posting it is too lazy to format the code to fit.

Answer (score 2):

No. Adding support for it will encourage people post even longer and less formatted walls of code.

You can already ask OP to edit question with true MCVE, format code nicely and in general make sure it is readable. If in some rare cases MCVE has to be too long - cut out important part of the code into main part of the question and provide complete sample at the end. In some cases such changes may be even done without OP.

Comment: I think moderator can choose which code need e.g. expanded window with a code when click on it or hover over. So this tool will be only for moderators. Or next tool- soft wrap like in Visual Studio. In default mode it is disable. User can press button and can see the way he/she like best. We can see how web and mobile aplications progress in last 10 years. We can make Stackoverflow more customised for users.